# Google Map API for India

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps for a website in india. Everything is good except one issue, there is border issue between india and pakistan. and google has resolved it(from map point of view) by using different domain names.

So on 
maps.google.co.uk it shows the problematic area(North West part) with a dotted line(in Jammu and kashmir)
but in
maps.google.co.in it doesn't shows the problematic area with a dotted line(in Jammu and kashmir) to keep indian government happy.

Now when i use google api url 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey

I get map displayed by maps.google.co.uk but not by maps.google.co.in

So is there any way we can specify the domain for map data returned by google maps api.

ofcourse https://maps.googleapis.co.in doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give an extra parameter `region` for API call to get region based map:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&region=IN
```

More info at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Region

Comment: This works good, somehow coudn't find this parameter, i did try with country=in :), anyways thanks a lot @user3280126

Comment: Do you get a country as India for Srinagar using this?

Comment: @AnupKalbalia You can try `PK` instead of `IN` (since Stinagar is a city in Pakistan). Check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization#Region

Comment: Thanks @alalp for the quick response. I will check that out. However, my concern right now is about those cities in the northern part of India, which are not coming with the country field even when I use region=IN. It is not just srinagar. Another example is Leh.

Comment: I don't know @AnupKalbalia, this is about Google's implementation I think. Do you see correct map when looking from maps.google.com?

Comment: Yes. I can see the correct map here: www.google.co.in/maps but not here: www.google.com/maps

Comment: @AnupKalbalia I can see expected results like in www.google.co.in/maps when I use `region=IN` (Srinagar city). You can open a new question with some fiddle (also some images maybe) which supports your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following code. I faced similar issue and the following code resolved the problem for me. The relevant argument in the context of your query is ... , region = "IN", ....

```
p <- get_googlemap(center = "India", zoom = 4, color = "bw", style = c(feature = "administrative", element = "labels", visibility = "off"), maptype = "roadmap", region = "IN")
```